# Excel 3D maps - Reorder Layers

Tags: excel, 3d, maps

Seems like a silly question, but is there a way to reorder the layers in Excel 3D maps? It seems that every time I add a layer, Excel creates it as the bottom most layer but there doesn't seem to be a way to reorder the layers once they're created.